# How to display very large strings i.e exceeding 1 million characters in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, string, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

I am creating a basic Swing GUI which displays very large strings (sequences) in a JTextArea, when a user selects the sequence ID from a JList. When the sequence string is <= 300,000 characters long, the JTextArea displays the sequence correctly

[image: 300,000 character sequence]
however, when the sequence exceeds 400,000 characters the sequence displayed on the JTextArea is overwritten and illegible
[image: 1 million character sequence]
How can I display very large strings in a JTextArea without breaking these large (>=400,000 character) strings?

My code:

```
public class GUI {
    private String[] stringArr;
    JList<String> idList;
    private JTextArea seqArea;
    Map<String, String> sequences;

    public void init() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel seqPanel = new JPanel();
        stringArr = new String[0];
        idList = new JList<>();
        idList.addListSelectionListener(new SeqListSelectionListener());
        idList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(idList);
        idList.setVisibleRowCount(12);
        seqPanel.add(scroller);
        idList.setListData(stringArr);
        seqArea = new JTextArea(15, 50);
        seqArea.setLineWrap(true);
        seqArea.setCaretPosition(0);
        seqArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane seqScroller = new JScrollPane(seqArea);
        seqScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        seqScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        seqPanel.add(seqScroller, BorderLayout.WEST);
        parseFile();
        frame.add(seqPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        }
        private void parseFile() {
            // function to simulate string that would be parsed from file.
            sequences = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            StringBuilder seq1 = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder seq2 = new StringBuilder();
            String[] bases = {"A", "C", "T", "G"};
            for (int i=0; i < 400000; i++) {
                int index1 = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
                int index2 = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
                seq1.append(bases[index1]);
                seq2.append(bases[index2]);
            }
            sequences.put("seq1", seq1.toString());
            sequences.put("seq2", seq2.toString());
            setList(sequences);
        }
        private void setList(Map<String, String> sequences) {
            stringArr = sequences.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
            idList.setListData(stringArr);
        }
        public class SeqListSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent le) {
            if (!le.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                String chosenSeq = idList.getSelectedValue();
                String sequence = sequences.get(chosenSeq);
                seqArea.setText("");
                seqArea.setText(sequence);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new GUI().init());
    }

}
```

Comment: Which Java distribution/version are you using? Since this looks like a bug, I would advice to make sure it's reproducible on the latest version, and if yes, then take it to their bug tracker.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior exists in Java 17.

Comment: A `JComponent`, which is the base class for a `JTextArea`, has a finite size.  If you try to put more characters than the component can hold, you get unpredictable results.

Comment: The tested code produces good results for the 2 testcases on my Windows machine. Tested using Java 15 and Java 17.

Comment: 300.000 is a sizeable fraction of what can go in an int (which is signed). Characters are about 8 pixels wide.  Could this be the number of pixels not fitting in a signed int? (May be font specific)

Comment: 1M characters also work fine

Comment: I am using Java 17.0.1 on Linux, so how do you suggest I display these very large strings?

Comment: When I was able to reproduce this behavior, it was in Linux.

Comment: (1-) You asked this question before and appear to have deleted that question. You still haven't provided any additional information to your question. The suggestion in the other question was to add a newline character occasionally. There should be no problem to hold 1M characters, the issue is likely that that can't all be displayed as a single line. I doubt there is any fix we will be able to give you.

Comment: @camickr so why are the strings displayed in the JTextArea when the program is run in Windows as stated by @coder? Don't you think the issue appears to be Linux-specific?

Comment: Don't know why there is a difference, But the main point is that whatever the issue is it will be deep in the rendering code and we likely won't have access to the code that is causing the problem. So you can work on a practical solution that will work on all platforms. Did you also try a JTextPane. It has a different rendering logic. Maybe it works  differently?

Comment: How is any user supposed to make sense of a 1 million character protein sequence?  There must be some shortened way that makes sense to present the same sequence information.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc These are genomic sequences and nucleotide level information is required for further analysis.

Comment: @camickr I have tried using the JTextPane but it appears to struggle more than JTextArea, 300,000 character long strings are not displayed in the JTextPane.

Comment: ...And you still haven't given results when you add a newline character to the string to make the string a more reasonable length. Why do you only test one suggestion at a time? *nucleotide level information is required for further analysis.* - so what does this have to do with a text component? You already have the text in a String variable so you use that variable to do your analysis. A text component is only for visual display and no human will ever be able to analyze a million character string by sight.

Comment: Just use a monospaced font and add a newline character after every 50 characters. It will still appear like a single string when displayed in the text area.

Comment: @camickr I will try changing the font and adding a newline character every 50th character. The sequence display is required in case the user wants to query the sequence online or in other apps. This bug has been reported for Linux users and apparently can be fixed by changing the x render java option (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8262010?attachmentViewMode=list)

Comment: *This bug has been reported for Linux users and apparently can be fixed* - Then post that as an answer showing all the relevant information that you used to fix your problem so others can benefit from the information.

Comment: @camickr Yes you are right, I have added the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is reportedly a common bug in the Linux environment (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8262010).

I fixed the issue by using

```
-Dsun.java2d.xrender=false
```

Java VM option when running the program, which turns off the XRender-based Java 2D rendering pipeline.