# How do you justify text in a JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, format, jtextpane

I am building a Java Swing GUI that displays a long string of characters in a JTextPane. To enforce a line wrap I have added newline characters after 70 characters to display the sequence on multiple lines of the textpane. Despite using the justify StyleConstant the text looks jagged on the right. Is there a way of straightening the text on the right side of the text pane?

Minimal example code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;
import java.awt.*;

public class Example {
    JFrame frame;
    JTextPane textPane;
        Example() {
            setComponents();
        }
        void setComponents(){
            frame = new JFrame("Example");
            textPane = new JTextPane();
            frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
            frame.getContentPane().add(textPane);
            addSequence();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.pack();
        }
        void addSequence() {
            String seq = "TAATCATAACAGGAAGGGGATAAAAAATAATGAATAAACAGGAAAACATTCAGTTTTAAGATACCTCAAA\n" +
                        "AGTTATTCTTCTGTAAATGTTCCTGTATTCCAATGGATTGTAGACTAGGACTGAGACATTAATCATCTGG\n" +
                        "ATTTCAAAATAAAACCTAGACTCAGTATTTGTTCCTCTTCCTTCTTCAGGTAGGAAGGCTACCCGGGGCA\n" +
                        "TTTCATCACAGGAGCTAGGGCAGGGGCTTTCAGGTGAGGAGCAGGATGGGGCCTCTGGGGGTGTGACTGC\n" +
                        "TGGGGACATAGCCACAGGGGATTACCTTCTTCTCACTCCTCACCTCCAGATTTGCACTGGGGCAAAAGGA\n" +
                        "GGATTAGGGTGTGTGGATTGCGGGGAGATAATAGTAGAAG";

            textPane.setContentType("text/html");
            StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
            Style style = textPane.addStyle("aStyle", null);
            StyleConstants.setAlignment(style, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
            try {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), seq, style);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Example();
        }
}
```

Current output:

[image: Example sequence with right side uneven]

Desired output:

[image: Desired output:]

Comment: Use a monospace font for your `JTextPane`.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thank you, it displays perfectly now :)

Comment: (1-) You were also given that advice in your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70568980/how-to-display-very-large-strings-i-e-exceeding-1-million-characters-in-a-jtexta. When we take the time to help, pay attention to the suggestions given. People don't have time to answer questions that have already been answered. Our time can be better spend helping people with real questions.

Comment: @camickr Apologies, yes I remembered as soon as I saw the suggestion.

Comment: @camickr Although the other question was a separate issue about JTextArea overwritting due to Linux X-rendering  and even with monospace I was having rendering issues. However next time, I will pay extra attention to comments, particularly yours :)